# Laravel 5, calling function inside compose@ViewComposer logs fatal error and returns result as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get the route name with

```
app('request')->route()->getName();
```

inside the compose method of my view composer which called by the boot method of the ServiceProvider.

The result returns as expected (foo.create etc.) but, when I check the log files,

Laravel 5 logs,

> exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with
>   message 'Call to a member function getName() on null'

And I can't understand how can an undefined function return the right object and I can call method on it.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got the current route's name in a different way and I did not see anything in the logs, so maybe try this:

```
public function boot()
{
   view()->composer([...], function($view){
      dd(\Route::currentRouteName());
```

About your error, I'd guess `->route()` is returning null, hence the error, so laravel sends the `getName()` message to the `app('request')` which works. Can you try `app('request')->getName();` or `app('route')->getName();`

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll try asap. Btw if I dd I also see no logs. I will reply after I try

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck with app('request')->getName() or app('route')->getName(), however Route::currentRouteName() works. I am going to use the facade and  stick with it. I upvote because you helped, but the question is not answered.